# git fsck --full reports no errors, but git merge reports fatal: unable to read blob object

Tags: git

I have a relatively large repository with approximately 130k commits.

If I run git fsck --full, no error is reported. However if I try to do a merge (an octopus), I get the error (while trying to do the merge):

```
fatal: unable to read blob object e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
```

does anybody have any idea how I can try to find the commit that is responsible for the error or how to fix my repo? Unpacking the commits did not help.

thank you for any help

Addendum:

the object does not seem to exist:

```
$ls -l .git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
ls: cannot access .git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391: No such file or directory

$ git cat-file -p e69de29bb
fatal: Not a valid object name e69de29bb
```

Comment: Have you checked if the object file exists? `cd /path/to/your/git/repo; ls -l .git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391` If it exists, can you get any output from `git cat-file -p e69de29` (probably would yeild the same error message though)?

Comment: No. it does not exist:(

`$ ls -l .git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391
ls: cannot access .git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391: No such file or directory`

`$ git cat-file -p e69de29bb
fatal: Not a valid object name e69de29bb`

Comment: Does `git fsck --full --no-dangling` report no issues at all? It seems like there should be a "broken link" report which should specify which object that refers to `e69de29bb`. Maybe you didn't see it because of alot of immaterial dangling objects? There must be a broken link somewhere, otherwise git wouldn''t be able to know that the missing object is a blob. If `git fsck` fails to find this broken link, that might even be a bug in `git fsck`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help: --no-danging reports no issues. I will try to contact the git mailing list and see if there is some obscure bug I am hitting. Here is the output: `$ git fsck --full --no-dangling
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (1370060/1370060), done.
Checking connectivity: 1370061, done.
`

Comment: Do you use shallow clone?

Comment: Does this error reproduce if you merge all branches without octopus, but one by one in a sequence?

Comment: check also what `git fsck e69de29bb` says

Comment: that is the hash of the empty object: `$ git show e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 | wc
      0       0       0`